# Expressing infinity in haskell

Tags: haskell

Is there a more elegant way of expressing positive and negative infinities in haskell other than `let posInf = 1 / 0` and `let negInf = -1 / 0` respectively?

Comment: The lattices package has this in general for any lattice, see Algebra.Lattice.Levitated. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lattices

Comment: Since IEEE754 infinities are, mathematically speaking, _horrible inelegant_ workarounds, I daresay you won't get off any better than `1/0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `Double` and `Float`: no, not really. For other types: yes! Those types that do not yet have an infinity may be given one via [`PosInf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monoid-extras-0.3.3.2/docs/Data-Monoid-Inf.html#t:PosInf) and [`NegInf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monoid-extras-0.3.3.2/docs/Data-Monoid-Inf.html#t:NegInf) type constructors. Some types may also have [their own special infinity](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numbers-3000.2.0.1/docs/Data-Number-Natural.html#v:infinity), but to say more than that we'd need to know what type specifically you want to use.

Comment: Thanks for clear explanation. Actually I wanted +/-inf for floats and I was sure I had missed something.